# can not delete record from database on the queue in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to send an email and the records save on the database then after 5 minute delete the records. I am using queue to send an email

it is my controller:

```
  public function send( Request $request){
    Log::info("Request cycle without Queues started");
      $this->dispatch(new SendWelcomeEmail());
      Log::info("Request cycle without Queues ends");
```

its my database

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('namemail');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

its my job for delete the records:

```
 public function handle()
{

   $user=DB::table('users')
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->delete())->get();
```

but it is not delete.
where is my problem???

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the queue? How do you run the queue? [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

Comment: @ ljubadr  with php artisan queue:table then php artisan queue:failed-table and php artisan migrate the last order php artisan make:job SendEmailWithQueueJOB. in send email job   public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
$mailer-> send('email.welcome',
    ['data' => 'data'],
    function ($message) use ($mailer) {
        $message->from('navidbezdar@gmail.com', 'navid');
        $message->to('navidbezdar@gmail.com');

    });

Comment: After all of these steps, did you actually start/run the queue worker? Check the docs [Running The Queue Worker](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

Comment: Note that `php artisan queue:work` is a long running process - if you change your `SendEmailWithQueueJOB` file, you have to stop and restart the queue. When you develop locally you should use command `php artisan queue:listen` - when you use this command you don't have to restart the worker manually when you change the code

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in this code segment,

```
   $user=DB::table('users')
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->delete())->get();
```

I think your delete job should be fail. Check your failed job table for reason.

The above code should be:

```
   $user=DB::table('users')
    ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1))->delete()
```